# updating in db from resultset

Tags: java, jsp

The SQL statement layers returns with more than one value, I want to update a column in db with all these values what is the problem here?

```
        String cust_code = session.getAttribute("Cust_Code").toString();
        String video_typ = session.getAttribute("video_typ").toString();
        int personal_p = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("personal_p").toString());
        int layers_p = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("layers_p").toString());
        String parent_cod = session.getAttribute("parent_code").toString();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ontube", "root", "123456");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String personal_po = "update customers set personal_p =personal_p + '"+personal_p+"' where membership_num='"+cust_code+"'  ";
        String first_layer="update customers set layers_p = layers_p+'"+layers_p+"' where membership_num='"+parent_cod+"'";
        int pers_points = st.executeUpdate(personal_po);
        int first_lyr = st.executeUpdate(first_layer);
        String layers="select membership_num from customers where parent_num='"+parent_cod+"'" ;
        // i want to update all values comes from these resultset
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(layers);

        while(rs.next()){
       String names =rs.getString(1);

       String update_layers = "update customers set layers_p = layers_p + '"+layers_p+"' where membership_num='"+names+"'  ";

       int  nms = st.executeUpdate(update_layers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change these lines:

```
String personal_po = "update customers set personal_p =personal_p + '"+personal_p+"' where membership_num='"+cust_code+"'  ";
String first_layer="update customers set layers_p = layers_p+'"+layers_p+"' where membership_num='"+parent_cod+"'";
String update_layers = "update customers set layers_p = layers_p + '"+layers_p+"' where membership_num='"+names+"'  ";
```

replacing:
`...set xxxxx_p = xxxxx_p + '" + xxxxx_p + "'...` with
`...set xxxxx_p = '" + xxxxx_p + "'...`.

**UPDATE**:
Also, don't use the same `Statement` for updates, while still reading `ResultSet`.

```
...
Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
while(rs.next()){
    ...
    int  nms = st2.executeUpdate(update_layers);
}
...
```

Comment: i cahnged them and nothing changed

Comment: the sql statment is correct i think the error in the update in the resultset but i dont know what i can do

Comment: @user2325383: NP :) If it did solve your problem, please consider marking the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

```
String update_layers = "update customers set layers_p = layers_p + '" + layers_p + "' where membership_num='" + names + "'  ";
```

should be:

```
String update_layers = "update customers set layers_p = '" + layers_p + "' where membership_num='" + names + "'  ";
```

Comment: it gives me this error   Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: The same with the personal_po statement.

Comment: nothing changed the same error the error not in the sql sytanx